# Trim a .mov file permanently to reduce file size

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm trying to put together a video based on a bunch of .mov files but need to reduce the file sizes so I can fit them on my computer. All of the base files amount to 89GB and I don't have that much spare disk space on my laptop so I want to bring them in one by one and edit the rubbish out quickly.

My understanding of Blender hard and soft cuts don't reduce the base file size. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You'll need to convert those files to another format ex. mp4 by using ex. handbrake.

Comment: Thanks tintwotin, I thought mp4 time was for the final export? Not sure that I want to compress it twice. I just want to be able to edit all of the dead bits out before getting to work on proper editing. Cuts in Blender seems to just hide the unwanted bits instead of deleting them which is what I want...

Comment: I've worked it out. I found a program called Lossless Cut which let's me quickly trim the video and keeps it in it's original format that I can now bring into Blender. Hopefully I can change 89gb down to 30 and start editing properly :)